# Go lang else is called first when it should not

Tags: go, for-loop, lexer

```
// Invalid token found, print error message and exit.
func abort(message string) {
    panic(message)
}

// Skip whitespace except newlines, which we will use to indicate the end of a statement.
func (s *Source) skipWhitespace() {
    for s.curChar == " " || s.curChar == "\t" || s.curChar == "\r" {
        s.nextChar()
    }
}

// Skip comments in the code.
func skipComment() {}

// Return the next token.
func (s *Source) getToken() Token {
    var token Token
    // Check the first character of this token to see if we can decide what it is.
    // If it is a multiple character operator (e.g., !=), number, identifier, or keyword then we will process the rest.
    // s.skipWhitespace()
    println("curChar: " + s.curChar)
    s.skipWhitespace()
    println("curChar: after 84 " + s.curChar)

    if s.curChar == "+" {
        token = Token{s.curChar, PLUS}
    } else if s.curChar == "-" {
        token = Token{s.curChar, MINUS}
    } else if s.curChar == "*" {
        token = Token{s.curChar, ASTERISK}
    } else if s.curChar == "/" {
        token = Token{s.curChar, SLASH}
    } else if s.curChar == "\n" {
        token = Token{s.curChar, NEWLINE}
    } else if s.curChar == "\000" {
        token = Token{s.curChar, EOF}
    } else {
        println("Unknown token: " + s.curChar)
    }
    s.nextChar()

    return token

}

// Process the next character.
func (s *Source) nextChar() {
    s.curPos++
    if s.curPos >= len(s.source) {
        s.curChar = "\000" // EOF
    } else {
        s.curChar = string(s.source[s.curPos])
    }

}

func do_lexing(codeString string) { // code_string = `+- */`
    // Initialize the source.
    source := Source{source: codeString + "\n", curChar: "", curPos: -1}
    // Loop through and print all tokens.
    token := source.getToken()
    println(token.text, token.kind, "token 119")

    for token.kind != EOF {
        println(token.text, token.kind)

        token = source.getToken()

    }
}
```

Output is

```
curChar: 
curChar: after 84 
Unknown token: 
 0 token 199
 0
curChar: +
curChar: after 84 +
+ 202
curChar: -
curChar: after 84 -
- 203
curChar:  
curChar: after 84 *
* 204
curChar: /
curChar: after 84 /
/ 205
curChar: 

curChar: after 84 


 0
curChar: 
curChar: after 84
```

It should print + and - token first and then give print the unknown token to the terminal but it prints unknown token first and then all other tokens.. I maybe missing something. I am new to golang.
println(token.text, token.kind, "token 119")
Also this line is not printed first

I tried adding printing statements

Comment: for s.curChar == " " || s.curChar == "\t" || s.curChar == "\r" || s.curChar == "" {
  s.nextChar()
}   fixed it by changing this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> println(token.text, token.kind, "token 119") Also this line is not printed first

You are calling `getToken` first before the above println statement and `getToken` has its own println calls, so it is only logical that the "token 199" isn't printed first.

> It should print + and - token first

No it shouldn't. You are calling `getToken` which calls `skipWhitespace` which calls `nextChar` **ONLY IF** `curChar` is whitespace, but `curChar` is `""` (empty string, which is not whitespace) at the beginning of your program. The output reflects the implementation.